# vba arrays and dynamically adding message errors to a msgbox

Tags: vba

I am trying to make an array that dynamically holds error messages

the following code works but is not dynamic in any way:

```
Dim Errors(1 To 4) As String

Errors(1) = "-Customer is blank on setup sheet"
Errors(2) = "-From is blank on setup sheet"
Errors(3) = "-Attention is blank on setup sheet"
Errors(4) = "-Job Number is blank on setup sheet"

For i = LBound(Errors) To UBound(Errors)
    msg = msg & Errors(i) & vbNewLine
Next i
MsgBox vbNewLine & msg, , "Missing Info"
```

how can i assign a variable to the variable name?

i am trying to do something like this:

```
num = 0
Dim Errors(1 To num) As String
```

I am hiding my errors inside if else statements and calling my loop at the end to display the errors. I am unable to use `Dim Errors(1 to num) As String` because an error is thrown saying "constant expression is required"

Answer (score 2):

Alilland, You're oh so close. What you need to do is use `ReDim` rather than `Dim`. Using `ReDim` will allow you to use a non-constant value to define the limits of your array. Thus,

```
num = 4
ReDim Errors(1 To num) As String
Errors(1) = "-Customer is blank on setup sheet"
Errors(2) = "-From is blank on setup sheet"
Errors(3) = "-Attention is blank on setup sheet"
Errors(4) = "-Job Number is blank on setup sheet"
For i = LBound(Errors) To UBound(Errors)
    msg = msg & Errors(i) & vbNewLine
Next i
MsgBox vbNewLine & msg, , "Missing Info"
```

Should work just fine for you. If not, please let me know.

Comment: your code works, unfortunately it doesnt work in my application of it :(

Comment: Is it something I can help you out with?